# Python SQLite Database values are not getting commited

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am trying to insert values inside a dictionary into a database using SQLite in Python. The dictionary has the following format:

```
    {'Hersteller': 'Budgetyarn', 'Name': 'Budgetyarn Acrylic DK', 'Preis': '1,23', 'Lieferzeit': 'Not available', 'Nadelstaerke': '4 mm', 'Zusammenstellung': '100% Acryl'}
```

I created a class for the database and the methods read a text file containing the data and converts it into Python valid lists. After that inside a for loop every dictionary is getting inspected and commited to the database.

```
    import sqlite3
import ast

class Database:
    def __init__(self, data):
        try:
            self.data = data
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect("searched_yarns.db")
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            self.cursor.execute(
                """CREATE TABLE yarns (Hersteller text, Name text, Preis text, Lieferzeit text, Nadelstaerke text, Zusammenstellung text)""")
        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            print("Database already exists")
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect("searched_yarns.db")
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def convert_data(self):
        with open(self.data) as f:
            yarns = f.read()

        yarns_list = sum(ast.literal_eval(yarns), [])
        return yarns_list

    def insert_into_database(self):
        yarns_list = self.convert_data()
        for yarn in yarns_list:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO yarns VALUES (:Hersteller, :Name, :Preis, :Lieferzeit, :Nadelstaerke, :Zusammenstellung)"
                                , {"Hersteller": yarn["Hersteller"], "Name": yarn["Name"],
                                   "Preis": yarn["Preis"], "Lieferzeit": yarn["Lieferzeit"], "Nadelstaerke": yarn["Nadelstaerke"],
                                   "Zusammenstellung": yarn["Zusammenstellung"]})
            self.connection.commit()

        print(self.cursor.fetchall())
        self.connection.close()
```

But when I run the fetchall() statement I get an empty list. I am new to databases and if it helps I am using Pycharm. Thanks

Comment: what was returned from `self.cursor.execute` ?

Comment: <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000001100ABFE340> as many times as how many dictionies I have

Comment: What are you expecting `cursor.fetchall()` to return here?